# Strange IE rendering problem with reporting services

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, reporting, service

I am generating a report based on some parameters.(I am using Reporting Services 2008, MVC 2 and Ajax as a development technologies). When i generate the report, if report has data everything would come up nicely. If there is no data, report body would be chopped off. Only empty table would show up. and there are some heading above the table which would get chopped off. This is happening only in IE.

But the strange thing is if i get the html content which is being returned to browser, save them in a .html file and open in IE, it would appear nicely(the way i wanted).

Answer (score 2):

This post is old, but this may help :
I had troubles with reporting services and Internet Explorer 8 and 9.
Some graphs were not displayed. Everything is fine with Chrome & Firefox

To work around my issue:

1. Open Developer Tools in IE (F12 key)
2. In the menu : document mode : chose Internet Explorer 8 standards instead of 'Quirks'

This is what worked for me !

Cedric

Answer (score 0):

Here is the layout of my report

Heading Label

Bar Chart

A Table

Page Footer

problem was whenever i did not have data i was hiding the chart but for some reason IE was hiding whatever was above it. So i handled this issue by setting the chart height to 0.001in rather than hiding it.

ok one issue is resolved

Now 2nd issue i am facing is, some of my footer are over lapping on the table row. it suppose to have a page and page # but instead footer is overlapping on actual data. 
Again this is happening only in IE :(